# Relation between dependent columns and invertibility

Tags: linear-algebra

Independent columns: Ax = 0 has one solution. A is an invertible matrix.

Dependent columns: Cx = 0 has many solutions. C is a singular matrix.

These statements are from Gil's LA. The full context is here:https://imgur.com/a/BSTRDpB

Can this be explained in greater detail? Why is it that when a matrix has independent columns, it is invertible? Is it a fact I should simply take at face value?

Comment: When you have a matrix with independent columns, its determinant is non-zero, that's why it is invertible.
Btw, have you studied rank, determinant, echelon forms and all?

Comment: @AnikBhowmick I have studied echelon forms and rank but not determinant. The two statements above are at the start of his book, before he has gone into ranks or echelon forms. Will I need knowledge of these terms before I can understand the statements? I keep running into this issue when using Gil's book where I need knowledge on a future topic before I can understand a concept his explaining...

Comment: Yeah I guess you need knowledge of these terms. They are heavily connected. For example, square matrices which have identity matrix as their row-reduced echelon form are the only ones which are invertible, and you know the relation between invertibility and determinant, and linear dependency of rows/columns will suggest you whether the matrix has identity matrix as its row-reduced echelon form or not. For example, a matrix having linear dependent rows/columns can't have identity matrix as its row-reduced echelon form and hence it's not invertible and hence the determinant is zero.